# "loading shared libraries " error, but the name is <garbled char>

Tags: linux, macos, ida, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I want to install IDA Pro for Linux(or [IDA Free](https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/) has the same problem) on my ARM64 Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine, which utilizes Rosetta 2 for compatibility.

After spending considerable time resolving environmental dependency issues and installing numerous packages, IDA Pro was able to run properly.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install binutils:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libglib2.0-0:amd64 libsecret-1-0:amd64
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:amd64 libxcb-icccm4:amd64 libxcb-image0:amd64 libxcb-keysyms1:amd64 libxcb-render-util0:amd64 libxcb-render0:amd64 libxcb-shape0:amd64 libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 libxcb-xkb1:amd64 libsm6:amd64 libice6:amd64 libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64 libxkbcommon0:amd64 libdbus-1-3:amd64
```

However, upon restarting the virtual machine, I encountered a shared libraries loading error again, with the characters appearing as garbled text.

```
$ ./idafree-8.4/ida64 
./idafree-8.4/ida64: error while loading shared libraries: ��: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The ldd output is as followed. Seemed that nothing dynamic library missed.

```
$ ldd-amd64 ./idafree-8.4/ida64
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007ffffea00000)
    libQt5Svg.so.5 => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libQt5Svg.so.5 (0x00007ffffe600000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007ffffdc00000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ffffd200000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ffffc800000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fffff6e5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fffff6de000)
    libida64.so => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libida64.so (0x00007ffffc000000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffffbdd4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fffff5f7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fffff5d7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffffbbab000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ffffede2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffffeddd000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffffedd8000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffffec9e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffffff80000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007ffffe948000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007ffffec68000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffffe943000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ffffe8cd000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ffffe4c0000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /home/parallels/./idafree-8.4/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ffffb800000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ffffe8c7000)
```

### Environment:

```
IDA Pro:  idapronl_hexarm64l_hexarml_hexmips64l_hexmipsl_hexx64l_hexx86l_230608_xxx.run

or
IDA Free: v8.3 (from https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/)

VM: 
   Ubuntu 22.04.4 
   Arch: aarch64
   Kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-76-generic (buildd@bos02-arm64-019) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #83-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 15 19:21:56 UTC 2023
  Memory Size: 2G
  
Host: 
  Model: Apple M3 Pro
  Memory: 18GB
  OS: MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1 (23D60)
  VirtualMachine Software: Parallels Desktop 19 for Mac (19.0.0)
```

## Some Attempts

### narrow down the package conflict search scope

I speculated that there might be a conflict between the installed libraries and the system's libraries. Therefore, I tried installing each library and then restarting the virtual machine to narrow down the search scope. After installing `libc6` and restarting, the error did not occur for IDA, but it indicated that `libGL.so.1` was missing. Upon installing the `libgl1-mesa-glx` package and running IDA again, the previous error reappeared.

### The garbled text

The hex code of error:

```
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~$ ./idapro-8.3/ida 2>&1 | hexdump -C
00000000  2e 2f 69 64 61 70 72 6f  2d 38 2e 33 2f 69 64 61  |./idapro-8.3/ida|
00000010  3a 20 65 72 72 6f 72 20  77 68 69 6c 65 20 6c 6f  |: error while lo|
00000020  61 64 69 6e 67 20 73 68  61 72 65 64 20 6c 69 62  |ading shared lib|
00000030  72 61 72 69 65 73 3a 20  01 91 99 3a 20 63 61 6e  |raries: ...: can|
00000040  6e 6f 74 20 6f 70 65 6e  20 73 68 61 72 65 64 20  |not open shared |
00000050  6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 66  69 6c 65 3a 20 4e 6f 20  |object file: No |
00000060  73 75 63 68 20 66 69 6c  65 20 6f 72 20 64 69 72  |such file or dir|
00000070  65 63 74 6f 72 79 0a                              |ectory.|
00000077
```

### The terminal version IDA

I try run the TUI version of IDA -- `idat`. The `idat` works well.

So I guess the error may caused by `libGL.so.1`.

## expecting

Running IDA Pro successfully.

Comment: amd64 != arm64 (aarch64)

Comment: @yvs2014 Yes, I know. IDA(amd64) can work with rosetta2 on arm64 VM. But didn't work after reboot the VM. That's my question.

Comment: I hit the very same issue. Doing An strace revealed it's looking for \1\221\231 as a shared lib... still investigating

Answer (score 0):

The “culprit” is actually the Rosetta daemon, which is probably used to speed up Rosetta:

For Parallels, the daemon is `/media/psf/RosettaLinux/rosettad`
It creates cache entries in `/var/cache/prlrosettad`

Killing the daemon is enough to allow IDA to start. Not ideal, but it's a good workaround until Apple(?) fixes the issue.

```
sudo pkill rosettad
```